# R shiny code for dynamic aggregation in a Valuebox

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm very new to R shiny coding. I am looking to calculate a sum in a ValueBox through the following code but am getting an error "could not find function "%>%""

Please help me make this dynamic. The data is available on the following link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0nKk-ptPFY1aWljWGk3bWVObDg

```
#UI
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

dashboardPage(

    dashboardHeader(title = "BCL"),   
        dashboardSidebar(width = 200,
               selectInput("typeType",    
                           label = em("Select Type",style="text-align:center;color:#FFA319;font-size:100%"),
                           unique(outcome_data$Type),selected = 'WINE', multiple = TRUE),           

               selectInput("typeSubtype", 
                           label = em("Select Subtype",style="text-align:center;color:#FFA319;font-size:100%"),   
                           unique(outcome_data$Subtype),selected = "TABLE WINE RED", multiple = TRUE),             

               selectInput('typeCountry',em('Choose Country',style="text-align:center;color:#FFA319;font-size:100%"),   
                           unique(outcome_data$Country),selected = "CANADA", multiple = TRUE),                                  

               selectInput('typeName',em('Choose Name',style="text-align:center;color:#FFA319;font-size:100%"),
                           unique(outcome_data$Name),selected = "COPPER MOON - MALBEC", multiple = TRUE)  
  ),  
dashboardBody(  
    fluidRow(   
      valueBoxOutput("DollarBox")
      )  
    )
 )




#Server
library(shiny) 
outcome_data=read.csv("C:/Users/Archika Kaushik/Documents/bcl-data.csv",stringsAsFactors = F) 

shinyServer(function(input, output)   
{      
     output$DollarBox <- renderValueBox({         
          filtered <- 
  outcome_data %>%    
  filter(Type == input$typeType,              
         Subtype == input$typeSubtype,      
         Country == input$typeCountry,
         Name == input$typeName)          
      valueBox(sum(filtered$Price), "Price", icon = icon("list"), color = "purple")   
    })    
  })
```

Comment: try adding `library(dplyr)` for a start.

Comment: Yes you need `dplyr` or `magrittr` packages.

Comment: It is working, thanks. But it looks like the aggregation is not working correctly. Is it because of lack of reactive function? And if yes, how can I use a column's sum inside the Valuebox?